# Converting String to Integer in Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin API

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have a few million edges in my graph that have a property called `Occurrences` - all of which have been entered as strings.

I would like to convert them to integers `('16' -> 16)` using Python, if possible.  Is there any direct way to do this that doesn't involve removing and replacing the edge?

Comment: What do you mean by "direct"? As far as I know changing a value requires replacing the item, regardless of what change you want to make.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but was hoping there would be a way to micro-edit.

Comment: Partial updates are apparently "coming soon", but no ETA: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6693091-be-able-to-do-partial-updates-on-document